# Java, delete Elements in an Array using counter , could anyone explain an example

Tags: arrays, sorting

I did not understand well how could i delete  an elment in anywhre in array then put an elment in the same position So there will be no empty spaces could anyone explain an  simpleexample

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
array[n] = newValue
```

This replaces the n-th element with a new value.